# Carousel of cards each having text followed by an image in cortana skills

Tags: botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

How to show a carousel of cards in **cortana skill**, wherein each card should **first have some text** followed by an **image**. Hero card does the exact opposite of it (First image and text later). I tried using the markdown `![alt](imagelink)` but it doesn't work in cortana. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cortana doesn't render markdown in `title` or `subtitle` of hero card; but it does in text property of hero card. So one way is to put the text and image markdown in `text` property and it renders properly.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully soon cortana will support [adaptive cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/get-started/bots#channel-status) For the time being you have a few choices that may work for you.  The closest to what you want is probably a thumbnail card.  Below are some samples of different cards you can take a look at and see if one works for you.

C#
[Rich Cards](https://github.com/JasonSowers/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-RichCards)
[Rich Cards - Carousel](https://github.com/JasonSowers/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/cards-CarouselCards)

Node
[Rich Cards - Carousel](https://github.com/JasonSowers/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-CarouselCards)
[Rich Cards](https://github.com/JasonSowers/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards)

Comment: Is there a projected date for enabling adaptive cards on Cortana?

Comment: The only news we have on this is "Coming Soon"